# Opening a json file from computer as a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I wrote the following function that I want to apply to a json file:

```
import json

def myfunction(dictionary):
    #doing things
    return new_dictionary
                
data = """{
#a json file as a dictionary
}"""

info = json.loads(data)
refined = key_replacer(info)
new_data = json.dumps(refined)
print(new_data)
```

It works fine, but how do I do it when I want to import a file from my computer? `json.loads` take a string as input and returns a dictionary as output and `json.dumps` take a dictionary as input and returns a string as output. I tried with:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\SONY\\Desktop\\test.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as data:
    info = json.loads(data)
```

But `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a file object instead of string. To fix that, you need to read the file first `json.loads(data.read())`

Howerver, you can directly load json from files using `json.load(open('myFile','r'))` or in your case, `json.load(data)`

Answer (score 0):

`loads` and `dumps` work on strings. If you want to work on files you should use `load` and `dump` instead.

Here is an example:

```
from json import dump, load
with open('myfile.json','r') as my_file:
    content = load(my_file)
#do stuff on content
with open('myooutput.json','w') as my_output:
    dump(content, my_output)
```